# Are meeting or going to meet

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

What is the error in the following sentence

> We are meeting today afternoon to discuss the matter and reach a compromise.

I think it should be **today in the afternoon** but in according to my book it should be **we are going to meet**

But I think there is no problem with this part of the sentence **we are meeting today**

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. You cannot say "today afternoon" (although you can say similar things such as "tomorrow afternoon" or "Friday afternoon").

> We are meeting today in the afternoon...

would be perfectly grammatical.

> We are going to meet today afternoon...

would not be.

Note that if you split afternoon up into two words, you can use it this way; saying

> We are meeting today, after noon, to discuss...

would be grammatical, though a little odd sounding.

Comment: We say _this afternoon_, not _today afternoon_.

Answer (score 1):

"We are meeting this afternoon" means "we are going to meet this afternoon". In other words the meeting for this afternoon is planned and expected. To use "today afternoon" instead of "this afternoon" is incorrect.